# Comparing javascript variable to PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a variable in javascript and a multidimensional array in PHP. I want to check the information contained in the PHP array to see which elements contain the equivalent of the the javascript variable, and then display those elements. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

I'm inclined to convert the PHP array to a js array of objects (remember, it's multidimensional) and do the comparison in javascript, and then use jQuery to output the right elements. But that all seems like a pretty big hassle for what seems like a pretty simple problem.

Is there a better way?

Comment: json_encode($php_array); //that's not too big of a hassle... although depending on the size, it may not be worth sending all that data to the client to do your calculations client side.

Comment: If the Javascript is in the client and the PHP is in the server, how do you plan on communicating between them?

Comment: @Missingo By converting the PHP into a JS array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two scripts, your PHP script and your JavaScript, are executed at different times. So, how is your PHP supposed to know what value is stored in the JavaScript variable? By a POST or GET to the PHP script. Once you do that, your PHP script can do the comparison and return the results in whatever format you wish (e.g. JSON).

Comment: I can't reload the page, so I think this is out. I proposed in my original post sending the PHP to JS (rather than the other way around), but is that not a good idea?

Comment: Who said anything about reloading? Use an asynchronous request (i.e. AJAX).

Comment: Yep, ended up using AJAX. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side script, and Javascript is a client side script. For that reason, it is impossible to pass a javascript variable to PHP, as PHP is generated by the server.

1. The user accesses a web page which is a PHP file.
2. The server processes the PHP page and renders/outputs a HTML page.
3. The user is viewing the HTML page.
4. Javascript happens on the page.

For that reason, it's impossible to pass a javascript variable to php, as the page hasn't rendered for there to be any javascript to pass. Although you can pass a php variable to javascript with `<?php echo $variable ?>`

There are 2 workarounds for this.

1. Use javascript to [set a cookie](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/), and have php retrieve the cookie value.
2. Give an html element on the page an attribute `itemid="43"`, and have javascript retrieve that attribute value of the element, upon an action (click,post), and post information to the php page.

Both have their security flaws, so code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. This is all good information so I hope someone finds it useful! (I ended up going with an AJAX request (sort of your second #2, I guess)).